# Selenium Java download file with Chrome to particular directory

Tags: java, automated-tests

I indicated a path for downloading a file but file downloads to another direction.

My Chrome properties:

```
File file = new File("./src/drivers/chromedriver" + (isWindows ? ".exe" : ""));
        String downloadFilepath = ".\\src\\test\\resources\\downloads";
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

I use the method indication direction and deleting a file from the folder:

```
public boolean isFileDownloaded(String downloadPath, String fileName) {
    File dir = new File(downloadPath);
    File[] dirContents = dir.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < dirContents.length; i++) {
        if (dirContents[i].getName().equals(fileName)) {
            // File has been found, it can now be deleted:
            dirContents[i].delete();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, I indicate the path and file name in the high-level method:

```
public void isSomeFileDownloaded(){
  actions.isFileDownloaded("src\\test\\resources\\downloads","SomeFile.pdf");
}
```

But file saves to another direction - it is default Chrome direction for downloads.
I have also used recommendation from the [Not able to download file in chrome(59 Latest) to a specific directory without any window popup using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816975/not-able-to-download-file-in-chrome59-latest-to-a-specific-directory-without-a) 
but the issue still exist
What I do incorrectly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the file being saved? I think that your path is not correct. Are you using Windows? take a look at this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=783

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows. The file saves to the C:\Users\User1\Downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, try using this:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory",System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "externalFiles" + File.separator + "downloadFiles");   
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: File still saves into default Chrome download location. Should I somehow change directory in the high-level method?

Comment: just edited my answer. Try to use "user.dir" property

Comment: It works with:
`HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory",System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "externalFiles" + File.separator + "downloadFiles");
            //chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);`